# JVM Optimizations for Docker and DC/OS

Tags: java, docker, dcos

I'm moving a bare metal java application (jar jdk8) to docker containers and DC/OS. I am noticing an odd pattern on the dockers, we set -XMX to 32 gig and allocate a 36 gig docker container. Every few hours or so the application will spike in old gen mem allocation and the GC will get stuck in a loop ( maxing CPU) while it tries to do the heap dump.

Are there any optimizations or things I can use to see why in that 1-5 second interval we are spiking so fast? Are there any gotchas I might need to be aware of with Docker and JVM?

We are using default GC

Comment: Well, you *are* basically giving the JVM a giant bedroom that has to be cleaned up occasionally. What sort of workload are you doing that needs that much heap, and what does its object lifecycle look like?

Comment: Multi-threaded app typically 5-6 threads all doing the same thing. Involves a lot of caching of data and large data sets. I do know that on a bare metal machine ( comparable specs ) the app itself has no issue, it may be the cpu allocation within DC/OS and Docker. I am going to try a few more experimental settings.

Comment: Does the heapdump complete if you don't set a memory limit on the container? Do you have anything that uses JNI?

Comment: I wouldn't wish JNI on anyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for future reference:

We are using JDK 8 and it seems as if Oracle has just recently added some experimental flags for using Docker. I believe the case could have been when GC was allocating threads it wasn't respecting the docker thread count from cgroup. The experimental flags seemed to have fixed our "off the rails issue"

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/java-se-support-for-docker-cpu-and-memory-limits

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would like to avoid this gigantic applications with > 30GB of memory and split your application into smaller parts with less memory requirements if you have the possibility to use a container platform like DC/OS.

In general about GC and heap size: If you have big heap sizes, full GC can take a long time. Personally I experienced full GC freezes up to a minute or more with a quite similar heap size to your mentioned 30GB.

About Java in containers: The JVM actually needs more memory than you configure with `-Xmx`. So, if you specify a memory limit of 2GB within your DC/OS (Marathon) application, you can not set `-Xmx2G`, because this memory restriction is a hard limitation. If your process inside the container will exceed these memory limit, the container will be killed. By the fact that the JVM will reserve temporary more memory than in `-Xmx` configured, this is really likely to happen. In general I would suggest to use around 75% of your configured memory as value for `-Xmx`.

You could have a look at newer JRE versions, which support `-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimits`. This is a JRE flag to use cgroup container limitations for memory consumption, see https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/04/04/openjdk-and-containers/ for more informations.

Comment: I understand all the points you made :) We have targeted 26 gig as our -xmx but as we are running multiple threads pulling large chunks of data it was easier to just expand the memory usage while scaling threads on bare metal. We've recently ported old legacy systems to docker and are modernizing so we are stuck with a few bumps here and there. Thanks!

Comment: When talking about threads and cores you might be consider about older JVM versions. Older JVM versions were not respecting cgroup CPU limitations. So we had funny side effects in the past, when the cgroup got 2 cpu assigned on a 64 cpu box, the JVM thought it could use all 64 cores. I think this was fixed in recent jre8 releases.

Comment: It was fixed in jdk9 and back patched to jdk8 131 or 141 version. Yeah without respecting c group :(